# CSS - Styles does not inherit properties

Tags: html, css, inheritance, styles

I have this code and I don't understand why my H1 and its associated P tag do not get the font and size defined in th BODY css element (no inheritence).. unless I uncomment the * css style, what is a really bad idea. And if I do so, I can't change their properties redefining them in the P css tag (inheritence seems forced).

I have this problem for maaany tags, and I don't wanty to have to redefine each time the font and size.

**global.css**

```
/*
* {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
*/
html {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px;
}

p {
    text-align:justify;
    margin:0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>a</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<LINK href="global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV>
  <TABLE width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <TR>
      <TD width="1" valign="top"></TD>
      <TD valign="top">
        <div>
          <H1>Title</H1>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You are only adding the font-size to the body tag. Not the actual h1 tag. You need to either define the h1 tag with the size you want or uncomment your * styles in your style page.

Answer (score 3):

Browser's user stylesheets style `h1` and `p`, as well as all other elements individually, which has a higher specificity than through `body`.

Style them individually to override these styles.

```
h1, p {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

You may also be interested in a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Answer (score 1):

h1 by default has font sizes associated with it by the browser by default you can either use a reset style sheet to solve this or simply.

```
  h1,p{
font-size:12px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

H1 and P both have native, browser defined styles that is different from the default browser style. Without any styling information, H1 looks different from text in just the body, right? For these reasons, you need to override them explicitly.

```
html, h1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The H1 element does not inherit font-size because it has font-size set in the browser’s default style sheet.

The P element does not inherit it because the element sits in a table cell and “quirks mode” in browsers means, among many other things, that tables break inheritance. Your page is displayed in quirks mode because it has no doctype declaration; putting `<!doctype html>` at the very start is the simplest way to avoid quirks mode, but many pages rely on quirks mode and go to pieces in “standards mode.”

If you uncomment the first rule, which uses the universal selector `*`, it will apply to all elements but will be overridden by any other rule in your stylesheet, such as `p { font-size: 5px }`. If this does not seem to be the case, then there is an error in the other rule—use the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to check the syntax first.